# WHERE xpath_exists clause not working in function

Tags: sql, postgresql, xpath, plpgsql

I've written the following function, which should return UUIDs from modules where the input `xpath_str` evaluates to true on the given `file_name`.

The below returns nothing. The problem area is the `xpath_exists`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_xpath(xpath_str text, file_name text)
RETURNS TABLE(uuid uuid) 
AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT m.uuid
    FROM modules m
    NATURAL JOIN module_files mf
    NATURAL JOIN files f
    WHERE xpath_exists(xpath_str, convert_from(f.file,'utf8')::xml)
    AND mf.filename = file_name;

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    --ignore a malformed xml doc
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I've tried tons of variants of equivalence checks to see that `xpath_exists` is true. None seem to work.

What's weird is, if I remove the `WHERE` and instead return another column of the `result` of `xpath_exists`, then select results from the function:

```
SELECT uuid FROM find_xpath('xpath string', 'file name') WHERE result = 't'
```

then it works. See below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_xpath(xpath_str text, file_name text)
RETURNS TABLE(uuid uuid, result boolean) 
AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT m.uuid,
        xpath_exists(xpath_str, convert_from(f.file,'utf8')::xml)
    FROM modules m
    NATURAL JOIN module_files mf
    NATURAL JOIN files f    
    WHERE mf.filename = file_name;

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    --ignore a malformed xml doc
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Seems that somehow the location of the `WHERE` statement is messing things up?

Comment: have you some examples of processed XML? It looks like data problem, not query issue. Please, recheck data.

Comment: Why do you say that? If using `xpath_exists` returns a T or F for every file it searches, then why would including it in the `WHERE` clause be different?

Comment: There are two constraints - maybe are not in good combination

Comment: Hm, you mean the `file_name` constraint as well?